# Finite union of compact is compact Proof verification

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness

I want to prove the following

> **Proposition.** *A finite union of compact subsets of a Hausdorff space is compact.*

I came up with the following proof which doesn't use the fact that it ought be a Hausdorff space which makes me doubt on my result:

*My attempt.* Let $(X,\mathscr{T})$ be a space and $A,B\subseteq X$ be compact. Let $\{A_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$ be an open covering of $A\cup B$. Then $\{A_\alpha\cap A\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$ and $\{A_\alpha\cap B\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$ are open coverings of the compacts $A$ and $B$ (respectively). Choose finite subcoverings $\{A_{\alpha_n}\cap A\mid n\in \{1,\dots , p\}\}$ and $\{A_{\beta_m}\cap A\mid m\in \{1,\dots , q\}\}$ of $A$ and $B$ (respectively). Then $\{A_{a_n}\}_{n\in\{1,\dots ,p\}}\cup \{A_{\beta_m}\}_{m\in \{1,\dots , q\}}$ is a finite subcovering of $\{A_\alpha\mid \alpha\in\mathscr{A}\}$. Indeed, let $x\in A\cup B$, without loss of generality, assume $x\in A$. Then, since $\{A_{\alpha_n}\cap A\mid n\in\{1,\dots ,p\}\}$ is a covering of $A$, necessarily $x\in A_{\alpha_n}\cap A\subseteq A_{\alpha_n}$ for some $n\in \{1,\dots ,p\}$. So $A\cup B$ is compact. By induction the result follows $\square$.

My problem with the proof is that at no point did I make use of the fact that $(X,\mathscr{T})$ was Hausdorff which makes be doubt on my proof. Is this proof correct? Is the requirement of Hausdorff an unnecessary one?

Comment: I think it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof demonstrates that it is indeed an unnecessary condition. Whenever a text does that I always doubt myself as well.